# Add missing day rows in stock market data to maintain continuity in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, etl

So I have around 13 years of stock market data of daily low high open close. The problem is the markets are closed sometimes in between and hence Monday to Friday might not appear continuously sometimes. Look below

|  | Date |  | Day | Open | High | Low | Close | Adjusted Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 17-09-2007 |  | Monday | 6898 | 6977.2 | 6843 | 6897.1 | 6897.100098 |
| 1 | 18-09-2007 |  | Tuesday | 6921.15 | 7078.95 | 6883.6 | 7059.65 | 7059.649902 |
| 2 | 19-09-2007 |  | Wednesday | 7111 | 7419.35 | 7111 | 7401.85 | 7401.850098 |
| 3 | 20-09-2007 |  | Thursday | 7404.95 | 7462.9 | 7343.6 | 7390.15 | 7390.149902 |
| 4 | 21-09-2007 |  | Friday | 7378.3 | 7506.35 | 7367.15 | 7464.5 | 7464.5 |
| 5 | 25-09-2007 |  | Tuesday | 7658.5 | 7694.25 | 7490.2 | 7629.15 | 7629.149902 |
| 7 | 26-09-2007 |  | Wednesday | 7647.1 | 7829.85 | 7591.8 | 7755.9 | 7755.899902 |
| 8 | 28-09-2007 |  | Friday | 7838.25 | 8082.85 | 7836.05 | 8042.2 | 8042.200195 |
| 9 | 01-10-2007 |  | Monday | 8008.55 | 8085.15 | 7913.3 | 7987.5 | 7987.5 |
| 10 | 03-10-2007 |  | Wednesday | 8029.8 | 8235.8 | 7820.25 | 8097.9 | 8097.899902 |
| 11 | 04-10-2007 |  | Thursday | 8083.3 | 8086.7 | 7828.65 | 8035.9 | 8035.899902 |
| 12 | 05-10-2007 |  | Friday | 8038.1 | 8066.55 | 7789.7 | 7845.25 | 7845.25 |
| 13 | 08-10-2007 |  | Monday | 7853.15 | 7935.45 | 7516.45 | 7626.4 | 7626.399902 |
| 14 | 09-10-2007 |  | Tuesday | 7580.9 | 7916.45 | 7535.05 | 7895.85 | 7895.850098 |
| 15 | 10-10-2007 |  | Wednesday | 7960.65 | 8081.05 | 7907.35 | 8030.65 | 8030.649902 |
| 16 | 11-10-2007 |  | Thursday | 8054.3 | 8177.75 | 8005.5 | 8158.8 | 8158.799805 |
| 17 | 15-10-2007 |  | Monday | 7962.55 | 8306.35 | 7962.55 | 8286.3 | 8286.299805 |
| 18 | 16-10-2007 |  | Tuesday | 8361.4 | 8491.65 | 8240.3 | 8452.2 | 8452.200195 |
| 19 | 17-10-2007 |  | Wednesday | 8071.55 | 8218.1 | 7641.5 | 8099.9 | 8099.899902 |
| 20 | 18-10-2007 |  | Thursday | 8055.15 | 8192.45 | 7519.7 | 7608.75 | 7608.75 |
| 21 | 19-10-2007 |  | Friday | 7637.4 | 7718.9 | 7279.3 | 7423.8 | 7423.799805 |

I want to have uniform data that has the same pattern from Monday to Friday. Hence wherever a day in between is missing, I want to replace its value with previous day values. For eg., between no 4 and 5, I would add 24-09-2007 Monday and then all other values copied from no 4 (Friday). Sometimes it can happen that consecutively 2 days are missing in that case again the last value has to be copied. for eg if both Monday and Tuesday were missing, I'd add Monday, copy Friday's data, then add Tuesday and copy Monday's data. How do I do it using python pandas? Remember there are 13 years of data so there will be leap years, year change, etc.

Comment: can you add the input as a dataframe to replicate the problem?

Comment: Please don't use images, but samples of your dataframe. Also, please post expected output. Make an effort before you ask others to do the same for you ...

Answer (score 5):

process:

1. set index of the date
2. resample the dataframe with 'D'
3. drop the day is Sat and Sun
4. fillna with 'ffill'

```py
# Data Index should be timeSeries
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

# upsample
dfn = df.set_index('Date').resample('D').asfreq()

# covert Date to Monday .. Sunday
dfn['Day'] = dfn.index.strftime('%A')

# drop Day in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']
cond = dfn['Day'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday'])
dfn = dfn[~cond].fillna(method='ffill').reset_index()
```

output:

```
        Date        Day     Open     High      Low    Close  Adjusted Close
0  2007-09-17     Monday  6898.00  6977.20  6843.00  6897.10     6897.100098
1  2007-09-18    Tuesday  6921.15  7078.95  6883.60  7059.65     7059.649902
2  2007-09-19  Wednesday  7111.00  7419.35  7111.00  7401.85     7401.850098
3  2007-09-20   Thursday  7404.95  7462.90  7343.60  7390.15     7390.149902
4  2007-09-21     Friday  7378.30  7506.35  7367.15  7464.50     7464.500000
5  2007-09-24     Monday  7378.30  7506.35  7367.15  7464.50     7464.500000
6  2007-09-25    Tuesday  7658.50  7694.25  7490.20  7629.15     7629.149902
7  2007-09-26  Wednesday  7647.10  7829.85  7591.80  7755.90     7755.899902
8  2007-09-27   Thursday  7647.10  7829.85  7591.80  7755.90     7755.899902
9  2007-09-28     Friday  7838.25  8082.85  7836.05  8042.20     8042.200195
10 2007-10-01     Monday  8008.55  8085.15  7913.30  7987.50     7987.500000
11 2007-10-02    Tuesday  8008.55  8085.15  7913.30  7987.50     7987.500000
12 2007-10-03  Wednesday  8029.80  8235.80  7820.25  8097.90     8097.899902
13 2007-10-04   Thursday  8083.30  8086.70  7828.65  8035.90     8035.899902
14 2007-10-05     Friday  8038.10  8066.55  7789.70  7845.25     7845.250000
15 2007-10-08     Monday  7853.15  7935.45  7516.45  7626.40     7626.399902
16 2007-10-09    Tuesday  7580.90  7916.45  7535.05  7895.85     7895.850098
17 2007-10-10  Wednesday  7960.65  8081.05  7907.35  8030.65     8030.649902
18 2007-10-11   Thursday  8054.30  8177.75  8005.50  8158.80     8158.799805
19 2007-10-12     Friday  8054.30  8177.75  8005.50  8158.80     8158.799805
20 2007-10-15     Monday  7962.55  8306.35  7962.55  8286.30     8286.299805
21 2007-10-16    Tuesday  8361.40  8491.65  8240.30  8452.20     8452.200195
22 2007-10-17  Wednesday  8071.55  8218.10  7641.50  8099.90     8099.899902
23 2007-10-18   Thursday  8055.15  8192.45  7519.70  7608.75     7608.750000
24 2007-10-19     Friday  7637.40  7718.90  7279.30  7423.80     7423.799805
```